# Template.pm : accessing passed hash in [% perl %]

Tags: perl, templates

I know how to access my passed hash in the Template.pm mini-language, but how do I access it in [% PERL %] fragments?  I am missing the obvious.

```
%vars = ( perldefined => "abc", somehash => { a => 'aa', b => 'bb' } );
$template = Template->new( { INTERPOLATE => 1, EVAL_PERL => 1} );
```

and now some examples

```
$in1 = 'a plain variables "[% perldefined %]".  a hashcontent variable "[% somehash.a %]".  good.bye'."\n";
($template->process( \$in1, \%vars )) or die "bad";
```

works.

```
print "\niterating over Hash in Template code\n";
$in1 = 'a plain variables [% perldefined %].  a hashcontent variable [% FOREACH key IN somehash.keys %] [% key %] => [% somehash.$key %] [% END %]  good.bye..'."\n";
($template->process( \$in1, \%vars )) or die "bad";
```

works.

```
print "\nHash print\n";
$in1 = 'a plain variables [% perldefined %].  [% somehash %] ]  good.bye.'."\n";
($template->process( \$in1, \%vars )) or die "bad";
```

works.  prints the hash reference.

and now where I am stuck:

```
print "\nHash print in Perl subcode, lack of knowledge making iterating impossible \n";
$in1 = 'a plain variables [% perldefined %].  [% PERL %] print somehash [% END %]  good.bye.'."\n";
($template->process( \$in1, \%vars )) or warn "huh?";
```

I need to know how to get this so that I can iterate over the hash keys and do other things.  probably trivially obvious answer, but I have tried all I could think of and failed.

Comment: Can you please show [the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of just the approach you've decided on?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/234299) Even though you can do really complex things with Template Toolkit, it's usually better not to. Why a `[% PERL %]` block instead of a simple [loop](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_Loop_Processing)?

Comment: because I like perl as a language instead of Template as a language.  less to remember, too.

Comment: That's exactly why you should do as much as possible in your Perl code *before* invoking the template engine. Even simple templates can be a pain to debug; things get much more complicated when you start adding arbitrary Perl code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `[% PERL %]` is pretty clear.

> Perl code is evaluated in the Template::Perl package. The `$context` package variable contains a reference to the current Template::Context object. This can be used to access the functionality of the Template Toolkit to process other templates, load plugins, filters, etc. See [Template::Context](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template::Context) for further details.
>
> ```
> [% PERL %]
>     print $context->include('myfile');
> [% END %]
> ```
>
> The `$stash` variable contains a reference to the top-level stash object which manages template variables. Through this, variable values can be retrieved and updated. See [Template::Stash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template::Stash) for further details.
>
> ```
> [% PERL %]
>    $stash->set(foo => 'bar');
>    print "foo value: ", $stash->get('foo');
> [% END %]
> ```

So,

```
$ tpage --eval_perl --define a=4 --define b=5 <<<'
   [%- PERL -%]
      print($stash->get("a"), "\n");
      print($stash->get("b"), "\n");
   [%- END -%]
'
4
5
```

From the documentation of ::Stash, it sounds like it's safe to treat `$stash` like a hash.

```
$ tpage --eval_perl --define a=4 --define b=5 <<<'
   [%- PERL -%]
      print("$stash->{a}\n");
      print("$stash->{b}\n");
   [%- END -%]
'
4
5
```

(Note that `$stash` contains more than the contents of `%vars`.)